# Smoldot Documentation

Tags: rust, runtime, light-client

How to run smoldot repository code and connect with our substrate based chain or substrate node ?
On official documentation of smoldot on github is not in detail .Please answer here complete way to use smoldot light client.
and Where can i find in depth explanation of connecting smoldot to substrate based chains.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of places to look for more information:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/substrate-connect/
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1382

The PR is still a work in progress, but might help to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run smoldot repository code and connect with our substrate based chain or substrate node ?

`cd bin/wasm-node/javascript && npm i && npm start` as per [README](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot#wasm-light-node).
I don't know if there is more in depth doc besides the code itself. IMO that is fine for a WIP repo.

Comment: I have already clone the smoldot repository but now where to test by using cd bin/wasm-node/javascript && npm i && npm start  ,

Comment: This assumes Linux, not sure what you are trying.