# Run Smoldot Light Client

Tags: runtime, evm, light-client, substrate-connect

Any one here who can tell me step by step how to

run **smoldot light client** and in which environment(ubuntu Linux , Windows) and what are the pre-requisite to run a light client ?

Comment: Does this not work for you? https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4718/94

Answer (score 1):

Smoldot light client can run as a Javascript node script. In Smoldot's (Substrate light client) repo (https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot#wasm-light-node) you can find the way to run a light client locally, and open app the polkadotJS apps with your local light client.

As a prerequisite I'd say you need node or deno installed in your machine...

**EDIT:** In addition to the "step-by-step" tutorial you can find in [this link](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/integrate-a-light-client-node/) a detailed tutorial on how to run light client in your dApp.